# upload multiple image in flutter app to a laravel api

Tags: laravel, flutter, api

Here is my function in flutter
I have use multi_image_picker to pick images sand i have save them in that variable images. Now I want post those images in laravel api. But this don't work.

```
    if(images != null ){
      try{
        List<MultipartFile> allMultiFiles = [];
        for (Asset asset in images) {
          ByteData byteData = await asset.getByteData();
          List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
          print(imageData);
          var multipartFile = new MultipartFile.fromBytes(
            imageData,
            filename: asset.name,
          );
          allMultiFiles.add(multipartFile);
        }

        FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
          'images' : allMultiFiles
        });

        var response = await dio.post(UPLOAD_URL, data:formData);
        if(response.statusCode == 200){
          print('done');
        }else{
          print('not save image. Error !!');
        }
      }catch (e){
        print(e.toString());
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is my function to store

```
public function save(Request $request){

        if(!$request->hasFile('images')){
            return response()->json([
               'upload file not found' => 'not found'
            ],400);
        }else{

            $allowedExtension = ['jpg','jpeg','png'];
            $files = $request->file('images');
            $erros = [];

            foreach ($files as $file){
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $check = in_array($extension,$allowedExtension);

                if($check) {
                    foreach($request->images as $mediaFiles) {

                        $path = $mediaFiles->store('public/images');
                        $name = $mediaFiles->getClientOriginalName();

                        return response()->json([
                            'message' => 'images saved'
                        ],200);

                    }
                } else {
                    return response()->json(['invalid_file_format'], 422);
                }

            }


        }



    }
```

It not work, images are not saved.
I'm beginner in flutter and thanks for your help.